# How to understand rabbitmq Variable Queue

Tags: rabbitmq

when I read https://github.com/rabbitmq/internals/blob/master/variable_queue.md, the variable_queue keeps messages on four queue data structures,but I am always confused why this design？Any one can give me a more intuitive explanation？

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"q4. The need for these four queues becomes apparent once disk paging is taken into account." Per the authors from the link you provided.

Have you ever ran into a time where your queue ran into the 44 million messages range waiting to be processed?  The reason for this design is those 44 million message have to go somewhere either the disk or memory, and going into memory would be really expansive.

Seems like the design for a variable queue is meant to keep messages in a queue while creating a buffer from the disk so you are never waiting for a message in any one of the other queues.

Essentially you have a queue of a queue of a queue that feeds queues messages being read from the disk to save on memory. Reading and writing to the disk is slow compared to writing/reading from memory, thus having this design seems to add some concurrency so you can keep getting your messages.

Comment: Most importantly, thank you for your careful answer！According to my understanding，the messages flows q1->q2->delta->q3->q4，the comsumer get message from q4, if happens to memory pressure,messages paging to disk by q3. q1 is used to store new messages when q3 is paging to disk. Does q2 is the buffer for q1 when q1 has memory pressure? Can q2 paging to the disk when q3 is paging to the disk?

Comment: @jiangnanxiang YES to answer you question, q2 can page while q1 pages, and q3 and q4 is paging to disk. The reason they all can page to disk at the same time is because they are all single threaded, running on separate cores.

Comment: I have not implemented this approach but, only read the documentation via the link you provided and also I have experienced what 44 million messages look like to process.. I can do 100k worth of messages per second in memory but only 20k when my queues are paging the disk. I am fairly certain the authors of the variable queues have it optimized in best case scenarios. I would download the library and experiment with it if I were you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience reply. I seem to understand it, I would learn more to have a deeper understanding. Thanks angin!